# How to display permission wise data in dynamic component using fluxor in blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor, fluxor

I am trying to create a dynamic component with data and using fluxor state. All are fine. All data are publicly visible. There are private data available. I want to display only permitted data. There is a field for permission. How to handle this? Is there any suitable reference?

Answer (score 0):

Withholding sensitive data can only be done on the server, not in the client (which is where Fluxor runs) - otherwise people could just look at the network traffic and see what the UI isn't showing.

If this is a Blazor-Server app then you can wrap your components with `@if` statements based on what the user has permission to see, this would be secure.